# Mostrar números con decimales como si fueran exponentes

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy tratando de mostrar números decimales como si fueran exponentes en flutter, como muestra la imagen. Si alguien ha logrado esto aunque sea en otro lenguaje me ayudaría mucho.

[image: Ejemplo de lo deseado]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Superscript y Subscript. [En este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet/44473979#44473979) explican como poder hacerlo.

Comment: Creo que el más simple resultado, es el copiado, donde reemplazas los valores correspondientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hecho reemplazando caracteres como me indicó [Excorpion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/131662/excorpion) :

```
decimalesEsponentes ("12.35");

String decimalesExponentes(String numero){
    String entero   = numero.split(".")[0];
    String decimal1 = numero.split(".")[1].substring(0,1);
    String decimal2 = numero.split(".")[1].substring(1,2);
    return entero+"'"+_parseExponente(decimal1)+_parseExponente(decimal2);
  }

  String _parseExponente(String n){
    switch(n){
      case "0":
        return "⁰";
        break;
      case "1":
        return "¹";
        break;
      case "2":
        return "²";
        break;
      case "3":
        return "³";
        break;
      case "4":
        return "⁴";
        break;
      case "5":
        return "⁵";
        break;
      case "6":
        return "⁶";
        break;
      case "7":
        return "⁷";
        break;
      case "8":
        return "⁸";
        break;
      case "9":
        return "⁹";
        break;
    }
  }
```